# Android - No suitable constructor found

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-fragments, android-activity

After rebuilding my project I get this error:

> Cannot resolve constructor 'Intent(anonymous android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener,java.lang.Class>)'

Does anyone what the error means, what is wrong with the constructor and how do I resolve this issue?

```
public class FragmentWCLine extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "Station_key";

    private class WC {
        private CharSequence station;
        private CharSequence zone;
        private Class<? extends Activity> activityClass;
        private Class<? extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment> fragmentClass;

        public WC(int stationResId, int zoneResId, Class<? extends Activity> activityClass, Class<? extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment> fragmentClass) {
            this.fragmentClass = fragmentClass;
            this.activityClass = activityClass;
            this.station = getResources().getString(stationResId);
            this.zone = getResources().getString(zoneResId);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() { return station.toString(); }
        public String getzone(){ return zone.toString(); }
    }

    private static WC[] mWC;

    /**
     * Whether or not the activity is in two-pane mode, i.e. running on a tablet
     * device.
     */
    private boolean mTwoPane;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_wc_line, container, false);

        // Instantiate the list of stations.
        mWC = new WC[]{
                new WC(R.string.bank, R.string.zone_1, WCBankActivity.class, FragmentWCBank.class),
                new WC(R.string.wat, R.string.zone_1, WCWATActivity.class, FragmentWCWAT.class)
        };

        final ListView listView = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.list_wc);
        listView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getActivity(), mWC));
        listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if(mTwoPane){

                    setItemNormal();
                    View rowView = view;
                    setItemSelected(rowView);
                }
                else{
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, mWC[position].activityClass);

                    String station = mWC[position].station.toString();
                    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, station);

                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }

            public void setItemSelected(View view){
                View rowView = view;
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#66CCCC"));

                TextView tv0 = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_station);
                tv0.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000099"));

                TextView tv1 = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_zone);
                tv1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000099"));
            }

            public void setItemNormal()
            {
                for (int i=0; i< listView.getChildCount(); i++) {
                    View v = listView.getChildAt(i);
                    v.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

                    TextView tv0 = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_station));
                    tv0.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

                    TextView tv1 = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_zone));
                    tv1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#B5B5B5"));
                }
            }
        });

        return v;
    }

    static class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        static class ViewHolder {
            TextView station;
            TextView zone;
        }

        LayoutInflater inflater;
        WC[] mWC;

        public MyAdapter(Context contexts, WC[] samples) {
            this.mWC = samples;
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(contexts);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mWC.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return mWC[position];
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        /**set selected position**/
        private int selectPosition = -1;
        public void setSelectPosition(int position){
            if(position!=selectPosition){
                selectPosition = position;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder viewHolder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_dualline, null);
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

                viewHolder.station = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_station);
                viewHolder.zone = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_zone);
                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            } else {
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            viewHolder.station.setText(mWC[position].station);
            viewHolder.zone.setText(mWC[position].getzone());

            //change item color
            if(position==selectPosition){
                convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000099"));
                viewHolder.station.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000099"));
            }else {

            }

            return convertView;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have a problem with the `Context` used for your `Intent`, change from:

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(this, mWC[position].activityClass);
```

to

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), mWC[position].activityClass);
```

or

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), mWC[position].activityClass);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get the error in **context**

do this...

```
Intent i = new Intent(fragment.this, activity.class); // It won't works
```

instead do this..

```
Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), activity.class);
```

startActivity(i);

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the line

`Intent intent = new Intent(this, mWC[position].activityClass);`

You will have to change that to

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),mWC[position].activityClass);
```

Answer (score 0):

you must define your intent befor your onItemclick method.

```
public class FragmentWCLine extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {  
Intent intent;  
...  
intent = new Intent(this, mWC[position].activityClass);
```

Answer (score 0):

At the position of 'MainActivity' Write your activity Name

Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,second_activity.class);

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).